# Why does Git have different config in Cygwin from Windows 7 Terminal?

Tags: git, windows-7, cygwin

I was under the impression that all Git config goes in some text file under the `.git` directory.  That doesn't seem to be the case because I added a `core.editor` config parameter in `Cygwin` to tell Git in Cygwin what text editor to use when amending or squashing:

```
git config --global core.editor "D:/homex/SFTWR/cygwin/bin/vi.exe"
```

I thought that was going to also take effect when using Git in the regular `Windows 7 Terminal` (the DOS-like CLI), which was OK because that `vi` executable actually works in Windows outside Cygwin.

But when I ran

```
git config --list
```

in Terminal, the core.editor variable did not appear.  All the other ones did.  So the config list in Cygwin shows 30 variables and in the Terminal 29.  I figure that if the config were saved in some text file within the project's .git directory, it should be the same for every interface through which it is accessed.

My Git editor works in both interfaces, that is not a problem.  I am just curious how this thing works under the hood and why Cygwin and Terminal show different configurations.

Comment: Are you using different versions of git for each? try running `which git` in Cygwin and `where git` in Windows Command Prompt and note the output.

Comment: no, it is the same:  `/cygdrive/d/homex/SFTWR/Git/cmd/git` in Cygwin and `D:\homex\SFTWR\Git\cmd\git.exe` in Windows

Comment: Do you have a `.gitconfig` file in your **Windows** home directory? i.e: `C:\Users\<USER>\.gitconfig`? I wonder if Cygwin and Windows are using different global configuration files.

Comment: my system config is highly customized.  is there a way to ask git where the `.gitconfig` file is located?

Comment: You could try `git config --global --edit` in both Cygwin/Command Prompt and see which exactly which is opened.

Comment: BINGO!!  Two different `.gitconfig` files.  The Windows one is in `C:\Users\<myusername>` while the Cygwin one is in `/home/<myusername>`.  If you put that in an answer, @rmorrin, I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that Cygwin/Windows are using two separate **global** `.gitconfig` files.

You can confirm which configuration file is being used by running the following in both Cygwin and Windows Command Prompt and checking which files are opened.

```
git config --global --edit
```

To fix this, you can delete the .gitconfig copy in your Cygwin home directory and replace it with a hard link to the .gitconfig copy in your Windows home directory. First delete the file, then open cmd with administrator privileges and run:

```
mklink /H "C:\cygwin64\home\youruser\.gitconfig" "C:\Users\youruser\.gitconfig"
```

More details about hard links are available here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/